# Twig - SQL request Result isn't displayed

Tags: database, symfony, twig, silex

I have only one table in my database with a couple of column whose one is called "description".
Using silex framework, when i do the sql request like this ...:

```
 $app->get('/', function () use($app){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM site";
    $post = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);
    print_r($post);
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array("site" => $post));

})->bind('index');
```

... every line and everything in my table are displayed, so everything is good.

When i use twig to get those results in my view like this ... :

```
{% for elem in site %}

     <h4>{{ elem.titre }}</h4>
     <ul>
         <li>Type : {{ elem.type }}</li>
         <li>Description : {{ elem.description }}</li>
         <li>Statut : {% if elem.statut == 1 %}en ligne{% else %}hors ligne{% endif %}</li>
         <li>Tags : {{ elem.keyword }}</li>
         <li><a href="{{ elem.site_url }}">Lien</a></li>
     </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

... every element is displayed except the "description" one where nothing appear. The name is correct since i have no error while loading the page. What I really don't understand is that element is well displayed with printr used before but not using twig in view.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo error on the description parameter? Or maybe the database return a null description...

Comment: I have more information about my problem. Actually, it's all about accent like 'é è ù ....'. When there are no accent the data is well displayed, if there is only one or more accent nothing is displayed. So i've tried to use twig like this : {{elem.description | raw }} but i have � instead of right letter.